# How to label bars on graph with numbers other than those on the y axis?

Tags: graph, label

From the examples of bar graphs I have seen here, the numbers on top of individual bars are those that correspond to the values on the y-axis.  I'd like to use another set of numbers or text on a bar graph generated using matplotlib.  How can this been done?  I' like to use the method shown in:
http://composition.al/blog/2015/11/29/a-better-way-to-add-labels-to-bar-charts-with-matplotlib/
but can't figure out how to refer to a list of labels which might be numbers or text.

Answer (score 0):

After several gyrations, the solution was relatively simple.  I passed a list of numbers to the function described in the link above replacing the "height" variable. Also, I prefer to have the bar labels always above the bar, so I just found the largest "y" value and increased the ax.set_ylim to 110% of that value. Not too elegant but meets my needs.